# Can I pass a Arc<dyn MyTrait> to a function that expects Arc<impl MyTrait>?

Tags: rust, types, traits, dispatch

In [Rust for Rustaceans](https://rust-for-rustaceans.com/), Jon Gjengset states (emphasis mine):

> When you’re given the choice between static and dynamic dispatch,
> there is rarely a clear-cut right answer. Broadly speaking, though, you’ll
> want to use static dispatch in your libraries and dynamic dispatch in your
> binaries. In a library, you want to allow your users to decide what kind of
> dispatch is best for them, since you don’t know what their needs are. **If you use dynamic dispatch, they’re forced to do the same, whereas if you use
> static dispatch, they can choose whether to use dynamic dispatch or not.**"

My interpretation of this was:

- In a library one should use: `fn execute(x: Arc<impl MyTrait>) -> ...` This is static dispatch.
- In a binary: `let x: Arc<dyn MyTrait> = Arc::new(my_obj)` This is dynamic.

Then I want to call `execute(x)`, but the compiler complains:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn MyTrait` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
12 |     execute(x);
   |     ------- ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |     |
   |     required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn MyTrait`
```

What am I missing?

Update:
One of MyTrait's methods is:
`fn build(conf: MyStruct) -> Self where Self: Sized;` where I put `Sized` in order for this method to be "skipped". In other words, this method would never be called from `execute` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. However, every generic argument in Rust is, unless explicitly stated otherwise, assumed to be `Sized`. So when you write

```
fn execute(x: Arc<impl MyTrait>) {}
```

That's equivalent<sup>[1]</sup> to

```
fn execute<T>(x: Arc<T>)
  where T: MyTrait {}
```

And since we didn't opt out of the `Sized` constraint, this gives

```
fn execute<T>(x: Arc<T>)
  where T: MyTrait + Sized {}
```

And while `dyn MyTrait` absolutely *does* implement `MyTrait`, it does not implement `Sized`. So if we write any of the following

```
fn execute(x: Arc<impl MyTrait + ?Sized>) {}
fn execute<T: MyTrait + ?Sized>(x: Arc<T>) {}
fn execute<T>(x: Arc<T>) where T: MyTrait + ?Sized {}
```

Then Rust will accept a trait object as argument to this function.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Almost equivalent. You can't write `execute::<MyType>()` if you're using the `impl` syntax.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I missed. Thanks a lot!